# I am facing Errors while working with nltk

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to execute basic operation with nltk
import nltk

```
sentence = 'I love bananas'
t = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print t
```

Answer (score 0):

run the following, and it will resolve your error. It is missing nltk resources.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```